# @media function not responding when trying to change height of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the height of a certain div.
Somehow, the div gets a default height of 964px.
When I'm trying to change the height by using `style: height:40vw;` inside the div tag, it works just fine, but when I'm using the @media function without the style, it doesn't work.
I'm referring to the div with class and id of parent-container.
Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="parent-container" id="parent-container" style="position: relative;top: 0;">
        <div id="video-container"
             style="z-index: -1; min-height: 100%;min-width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0;left: 0; transition-delay: 500ms;overflow-y: hidden">
            <video class="fade-in" autoplay loop muted
                   style="min-width:100%;max-height:100% ;position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; object-fit: fill;">
                <source id="mp4" src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 video elemnt</p>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="videoRGBA">
            <img src="images/brush.png" style="position: relative; top: 15vw; left: 50px">
            <div style="position: relative; top: 0.8vw;">
                NOT RELEVANT
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-width 427px){
    .parent-container{
      height: 100vw;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width 0px) and (max-width 426px){
    .parent-container{
        height:90vw;
    }
}

Thanks.
```

Comment: You are changing css in the media query. Are you looking the output any mobile device??

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Are you looking output in a laptop or mobile device??

Comment: Both. Currently on a laptop, but I'm using ctrl+shift+c to check the output in each type of screen.

Answer (score 0):

I missed ":" in the media query.
instead of

```
@media only screen and (min-width 427px){
    .parent-container{
      height: 100vw;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width 0px) and (max-width 426px){
    .parent-container{
        height:90vw;
    }
}
```

Just changed to:

```
@media only screen and (min-width :427px){
    .parent-container{
      height: 100vw;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 426px){
    .parent-container{
        height:90vw;
    }
}
```